Why isn’t my optimistic UI updating immediately
I’ve got this React component where I’m testing out useOptimistic to simulate an optimistic UI update. The tricky part is, I don’t have a real backend, so I’m using a mock data source (messagesOnApi) from another module. I load that data into a local state variable (messagesRetrievedFromApi) and pass it into useOptimistic.
The idea is that when I add a new message, I want the UI to update instantly (optimistically), while I add a 2-second delay before simulating the "API" response. The problem is that the optimistic update only happens after the delay, rather than immediately as I’d expect. I’m not sure what’s causing the delay in the optimistic update.
Here is the code im working on

import { useOptimistic, useState, useTransition, useEffect } from "react";
import { Message, messagesOnApi } from "./MessagesData";

export function OptimisticMessages() {
  const [messagesRetrievedFromApi, setMessagesRetrievedFromApi] = useState<Message[]>([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [optimisticMessages, addOptimisticMessage] = useOptimistic<Message[], string>(
    messagesRetrievedFromApi,
    (currentMessages, message) => {
      const finalMessages = [
        ...currentMessages,
        { id: getNextId(currentMessages), message },
      ];
      return finalMessages;
    }
  );
  const [_isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(messagesOnApi));
    setMessagesRetrievedFromApi(data);
  }, []);

  const addMessage = async (message: string) => {
    addOptimisticMessage(message);
    await new Promise((res) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        messagesOnApi.push({
          id: getNextId(messagesOnApi),
          message,
        });
        res(null);
      }, 2000)
    );
    const data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(messagesOnApi));
    setMessagesRetrievedFromApi(data);
    setMessage("");
  };

  const onClick = async () => {
    startTransition(() => {
      addMessage(message);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={message} onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={onClick}>Add</button>
      <ul>
        {optimisticMessages.map((m, i) => (
          <li key={i}>{m.message}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

function getNextId(currentMessages: Message[]) {
  let id = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < currentMessages.length; i++) {
    if (currentMessages[i].id > id) id = currentMessages[i].id;
  }
  return id + 1;
}




You're not actually using a passive event listener here

With React at least, you generally would not install your own event listeners, you'd let React do it. What's wrong with rendering <form onSubmit={formData}>?
